# Как сравнить данные взятые из двух разных методов

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

Мне нужно сравнить между собой текст взятый из двух разных методов.
У меня есть два метода которые берут текст из указанного Xpath

```
public class GlobalPage {
    private String ByXpath = "xpath:>%s";

//первый
public String someMethod(String xpath1) {
       WebElement options1 = driverWrapper.findElementByUntilWait(ByXpath, xpath1);
       return options1.getText();
    }

//второй
public String someMethod(String xpath2) {
       WebElement options2 = driverWrapper.findElementByUntilWait(ByXpath, xpath2);
       return options2.getText();

    }
//и  третий в котором я хочу сравнить взятые тексты с помощью assertEquals (воможно другого способа)
public void equal() {
        Assert.assertEquals(this.anotherMethod(), this.someMethod());
    }
}
```

Подскажите, есть ли вообще такая возможность и если есть то в какую сторону копать. или воззможно подскажете правильный вариант решения этой задачи
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "сравнить"? по какому критерию?

Comment: Простите, а зачем Вам два метода которые делают одно и то же? Может просто стоит вызывать один и тот же метод и просто передавать в него разные значения, а  не создавать отдельно метод под каждый возможный путь, который вы и так передаете

Comment: @Konstantin_SH "сравнить" что текст взятый из первого элемента соответствует тексту взятому из второго елемента

Comment: @МихаилРебров методы вызываются раззными степами в Gherkin и между этими степами могут происходить еще разные дополнительные действия, например перейти на другую страницу или закрыть текущтй попап

Comment: @МаксимГоловненко, все зависит от того как Вы Page реализовали. Скорее всего у вас объект страницы, будет создаваться каждый раз, как вы заходите на эту страницу. `Gherkin`ы и прочие кукумберы я не очень то люблю, если честно и не работаю с ними. Поэтому сложно сказать как вам помочь в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

Assert.assertEquals(someMethod("какой-то xpath", someMethod("какой-то другой xpath"))

p.s.  этот код лишний и его можно удалить

```
//второй
public String someMethod(String xpath2) {
       WebElement options2 = driverWrapper.findElementByUntilWait(ByXpath, xpath2);
       return options2.getText();

    }
```